# Using bootstrap javascript in a Rails 7 app

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5, esbuild, ruby-on-rails-7

I have a working Rails 7 app that uses esbuild as the JS bundler and have imported bootstrap.

I am trying to figure out how to a access any Bootstrap Javascript functionality 'outside' the main application.js file - i.e. let's say I wanted to programatically show a Bootstrap modal on a particular page like this:

```
var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('helpModal'), {});
myModal.modal('show');
```

however this doesn't work as 'bootstrap' is not known:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: bootstrap is not defined
```

...even though the page links in application.js:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", defer: true %>
```

Any suggestions on how to access 'bootstrap' in JS outside application.js itself ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you created your rails app with:

`rails new APP_NAME --css=bootstrap ...`

Which creates your app with `ESBUILD` and leaves you with a `app/javascripts/application.js` file looking like this:

```
// Entry point for the build script in your package.json
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "./controllers"
import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap"
```

You now need to code in the modal to use the imported bootstrap.

Add the code you have in your question below the `bootstrap` import line:

```
// Modals
var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('helpModal'), {});
myModal.modal('show');

// Or to have it triggered using a button
document.getElementById('helpModalButton').addEventListener('click', event => {
  myModal.show();
});
```

This will turn on the event handlers

More can be found on the Bootstrap Docs page for each of the Components (the same applies to Modals and Popovers)

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/modal/#passing-options

Comment: This of course works, but the question asks "how to access any Bootstrap Javascript functionality 'outside' the main application.js file". I have a similar problem: an "import library" after the "import bootstrap" where I get an "bootstrap is not defined" inside that imported library.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to help fix that error in an imported library but to reference bootstrap from a JS file within my app (but outside application.js) I duplicated the `import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap"` command in my Javascript file...

```js
//app/javascript/popovers.js

console.log('Loading popovers...')

import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap"

const popoverTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]')
const popoverList = [...popoverTriggerList].map(popoverTriggerEl => new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl))
```

Then I imported that file from my main `application.js`:

```js
//app/javascript/application.js

// Entry point for the build script in your package.json
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "./controllers"
import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap"
import "./popovers.js"
```

For me, I was [trying to reference `bootstrap`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77791042/how-do-i-get-bootstrap-5-3-popovers-to-display-in-a-rails-7-esbuild-app/77791082#77791082) so I could [initialise Popovers](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/popovers/).

Answer (score 0):

I just removed Gemfile.lock in my project and updated the gems using the command `gem update --system`.finally insatll gems using bundler `bundle install` I hope that works for you.