# How do I get Bootstrap 5.3 popovers to display in a Rails 7 esbuild app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-5, esbuild

When I create a brand new Rails 7 app with Bootstrap, Modals work out of the box but Popovers don't. How do I get them to work?

Rails 7.1.2, esbuild, Bootstrap 5.3.2:

```bash
rails new --database sqlite3 --javascript esbuild --css bootstrap bootstrap_test
cd bootstrap_test
bin/setup
rails g scaffold page
edit app/views/pages/index.html.erb #see below
bin/dev
```

```html
#app/views/pages/index.html.erb
<h1 class="display-1">Hello Bootstrap</h1>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalXl" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalXlLabel" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-4" id="exampleModalXlLabel">If you can see this...</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Modals are working 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModalXl">Modal test</button>
<br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-title="If you can see this..." data-bs-content="Popovers are working ">Popover test</button>
```

According to the [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/popovers/):

> Popovers are opt-in for performance reasons, so **you must initialize them yourself**.

I tried putting their suggested initialisation code in but I get a `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: bootstrap`:

```js
console.log('Loading popovers...')

const popoverTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]')
const popoverList = [...popoverTriggerList].map(popoverTriggerEl => new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl))
```

At one point I tried initialising them via Stimulus but I couldn't get that working either.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Where did you place your script?

Answer (score 0):

After posting my question I found [a similar/related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71166303/145725) which helped me find **a** solution.

To reference `bootstrap` from a JS file within my app, I duplicated the `import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap"` command from the main `application.js` file...

```js
//app/javascript/popovers.js

console.log('Loading popovers...')

import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap"

const popoverTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]')
const popoverList = [...popoverTriggerList].map(popoverTriggerEl => new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl))
```

Then I imported that file from my main `application.js`:

```js
//app/javascript/application.js

// Entry point for the build script in your package.json
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "./controllers"
import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap"
import "./popovers.js"
```

Now popovers and modals are both displaying. I just have to figure out how to dismiss the popovers when I click somewhere else in the document

[image: Popovers working... but obscuring a modal]

Comment: The solution I give (below) is for a new rails 7.1 app created via `rails new myapp --css=bootstrap`, and I just tried and popovers work as expected. The first time I tried I was using an old node version (16), and bootstrap/sass wasn't installing correctly (the rails app was created, but there were non-halting errors during its creation). Try create a new app with and watch the logs closely for errors related to bootstrap/node/sass. When you created the app it might have had errors that you didn't notice. When I switched to a recent node version (via `nvm use v20.9.0`), those errors went away

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think is best practice. It assumes you have a rails 7.1 app with esbuild and bootstrap. It could be created via:

```bash
rails new myapp --css=bootstrap
```

Add popover (example taken from [bootstrap 5.3 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/popovers/#live-demo)) to a view (so we'll be able to click on it to confirm that it works):

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-bs-toggle="popover" 
data-bs-title="Popover title" 
data-bs-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">
Click to toggle popover</button>
```

And copy/paste [these 2 lines](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/popovers/#enable-popovers) to the bottom of `app/javascript/application.js`:

```js
const popoverTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]')
const popoverList = [...popoverTriggerList].map(popoverTriggerEl => new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl))
```

Start the rails server with `bin/dev`, and click on the button to see the popover appear:

[image]